# gcc remove unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, centos

My GCC compiler always shows the following error when its used to compile anything on the server

```
gcc: unrecognized option '-Qunused-arguments'
```

Any idea what it is? Also how can I remove it?

```
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I suspect its one of the flags that was added long ago but I have no idea how to remove this option, doesnt really affect anything but it is very very annoying!

Thank you!

Comment: How are you invoking the compiler? Do you get that error when you type `gcc foo.c`?

Comment: gcc: foo.c: No such file or directory
gcc: no input files , the compiler is invoked by installation scripts from python tools.

Comment: It's a bug in the installation script. Where did the script come from?

Comment: actually i encounter this error with whatever i install if the gcc compiler is used. I am thinking there is sth wrong with the actual options with gcc on the server and not from the scripts

Comment: `gcc` itself does not specify any options. *Something* must be passing options to the `gcc` command. How *exactly* are you invoking gcc, and what software are you trying to build?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add some information:

`-Qunused-arguments` is a compiler option of the `clang`-compiler, an alternative to `gcc`. This is probably defined in some `Makefile` called file.

As this option just suppresses some warnings `clang` will print, it's probably the best to remove this option from the Makefile.

The only thing I am wondering about: if you call `gcc` from within the Makefile you must already have changed this Makefile as with the named option the compiler to use by this Makefile probably originally was `clang`.